# CartoDB table join error: Column reference is ambiguous

Tags: carto, sql, attribute-joins, table

I've got a CartoDB question that seems dumb b/c the layer is correctly rendering. Anyway, I have two layers, named

- sampling_points
- sample_point

I'm trying to inner join the sample_point data to the sampling_points. Basically to render all sampling_points that have their id (suid) in the sample_point table.

Here's my code.

```
     SELECT sampling_points.the_geom_webmercator, sampling_points.suid, sample_point.suid
     FROM sampling_points, sample_point
     WHERE sampling_points.suid = sample_point.suid
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sampling_points.the_geom_webmercator, sampling_points.suid, sample_point.suid
 FROM sampling_points, sample_point
 WHERE sampling_points.suid = sample_point.suid
```

This query is generating two final columns called `suid`, so the ambiguity is not in the query itself but in the selected results, to sort this out, use alias:

```
SELECT sampling_points.the_geom_webmercator, 
sampling_points.suid as suidsampling, sample_point.suid as suidsample
FROM sampling_points, sample_point
WHERE sampling_points.suid = sample_point.suid
```